# WildFly Jboss: Failed to load annotated class

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I am new to Wildlfy and JBoss and I now tried to deploy my Project with a `.war` file on a WildFly Server. I am currently getting the following error:

```
2017-06-26 12:43:09,128 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit.SmartVis.INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.SmartVis.INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "SmartVis"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:172)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJSF0008: Failed to load annotated class: com.consolinno.smartvis.converter.BhkwConverter
    at org.jboss.as.jsf.deployment.JSFAnnotationProcessor.deploy(JSFAnnotationProcessor.java:115)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:165)
    ... 5 more

2017-06-26 12:43:09,163 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 7) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "SmartVis-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.SmartVis.INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.SmartVis.INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"SmartVis\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJSF0008: Failed to load annotated class: com.consolinno.smartvis.converter.BhkwConverter"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.SmartVis.INSTALL",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.SmartVis.beanmanager"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.SmartVis.weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.SmartVis.beanmanager]",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.SmartVis.batch.environment is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.SmartVis.beanmanager]"
    ]
}
2017-06-26 12:43:09,165 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request Threads -- 7) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "SmartVis" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.SmartVis.INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.SmartVis.INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"SmartVis\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJSF0008: Failed to load annotated class: com.consolinno.smartvis.converter.BhkwConverter"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.SmartVis.INSTALL",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.SmartVis.beanmanager"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.SmartVis.weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.SmartVis.beanmanager]",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.SmartVis.batch.environment is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.SmartVis.beanmanager]"
    ]
}
```

The class `BhkwConverter` is a simple Converter Class used for a `SelectOneMenue` of `Primefaces`. I have a `bean.xml` file in "WEB-INF" directory.

Can someone give me an advice here? I can't find anything similar on google.

Comment: The file must be named `beans.xml`

Comment: Typo, it is named beans.xml

Comment: I have the same problem, mi app was running on glassfish but I triying to migrate to WildFly. The error that I have also is related to a simple Converter of Primefaces, the difference is that I dont have a beans.xml file. What is supposed to be written in that file? Do I need an additional configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I forgot to add the

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.modules</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-modules</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

to the pom.xml file. Working perfectly now.

Comment: This dependency should not be needed and should at least be marked as `<scope>provided</scope>`.